# Incomplete LU factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I understand how to compute a LU factorization but I struggle to find any examples how to compute a Incomplete LU factorization. Could someone please give an example? Would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I suggest https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Its-Applications-4th/dp/0030105676